# Build IOS with ionic Pro

Tags: ionic3

I'm Trying to build my app with ionic pro package and i get this error

```
[13:46:18]: Error setting value '/Users/ionic/builds/cervejame/cervejame-web/platforms/ios/Cerveja.me.xcodeproj' for option 'path'
[13:46:18]: You passed invalid parameters to 'update_project_codesigning'.
[13:46:18]: Check out the error below and available options by running `fastlane action update_project_codesigning`
```

can anyone help me with that

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error suggested? Also, what's the 'error below' that was mentioned?

Comment: that is the problem, this error is inside ionic pro, i cant run this suggestion manually

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I'm encountering the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you already solved the problem, still wanted to leave an answer for others who might encounter this problem.

I had two scripts; updating pods and running pods which where run as hooks before and after build, since a certain plugin (googlemaps) required a newer version of cocoapods. This error originated on a typo in these scripts (embarrassingly, on the #!/bin/bash/).

Without more info on your app or the error output, i couldn't say if this was/is your case.

But as bottom line; if you have any scripts on hooks, check for mistakes.